# Big Views query and PHP memory limits

Tags: views

I have a custom table, from which I create a paged table using views and data module.
When I get somewhere over 15000 rows, PHP runs out of memory. Is there any way to avoid this?
Thanks

Comment: It is feasible, can you post the SQL from the query?  Also, what row format (content, fields, etc)?  There is one quirk I know of, but I am not sure if you are experiencing it.

Comment: I think this should be the base query that's run when I open the page: http://pastebin.com/daJ598Uj

Comment: Are you displaying 15000 rows in a page in view?

Comment: Yes, 26.000 right now, 50 per page.

Comment: @Maiagallo Can you paste the entire query, including the JOINs?

Comment: I'm not really sure on how to get the entire query. I think there shouldn't be any JOINs: it's just data coming straight from a custom table.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your memory limit on your server is too low.

Have a look under Reports >> Status report what it is.
Default on most servers are 32M. This is too low.

If you do not manage your own server then go beg your server admin to increase it. I can't give you a number, best to increase in 32Mb steps until you are happy.
I normally set mine to 256Mb during development and drop it to 128Mb on fairly large sites (this is just a guideline what I do).

If your server admin does not want to change it then first answer would be to get a new provider, which I know is not always the correct route. But read here how you might be able to set it yourself. [Increase PHP settings](https://drupal.org/node/207036)

Comment: Of course it's a memory limit problem... I just found out that my hosting increased the memory limit, so I went from 128M to 256M, but it didn't help much: with 16.000 records I have 132M peak, with 27.000 records 192M peak. This means 5M of ram every thousand record. I'm looking for a way to reduce the memory used per record, as I'll need to get up to a hundred thousands probably...